# Non WAR JSP spring-boot example

Tags: spring-boot

I've been checking out most of all spring-boot provided examples for JSP as view technologie are being packaged as WAR artifacts.

Would be nice to provide a jar example for this if possible?

I know that JSP requires a Servlet Engine/Servlet Container  as opposed as e.g Freemarker .. for rendering .. but being Jetty or Tomcat Servlet Containers is this option viable and possible ?

Trying that setup so far with not much success, my last try was to create a

META-INF/resources folder to put all those jsp resources but they are still not visible to the ViewResolver

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/META-INF/resources/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setOrder(2);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

At the end.. was trying some setup like here:

http://alexismp.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/web-inflib-jarmeta-infresources/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible (owing to limitations imposed by the containers): http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Answer (score 0):

This is not a *jar* answer, but still a *non WAR* one :)

Put your JSP files under:

```
{ "src/main/webapp", "public", "static" }
```

The code is taken from [AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java). Now I find the spring-boot reference misleading ([27.1.5 Static Content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)). It mentions several directories for static content, but says nothing about those above. But still I'm happy it's an open source world and UTSL works :)

As you can see the `resources` dir is not included. The [JSP sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) (mentioned under 27.3.5 JSP limitations) works well, because it uses `src/main/webapp` for jsp file.

The root directory is chosen on a **first match basis**. And ServletContainerFactory anounces a debug (fine) level message mentioning `.ocument root`. You can look for it, whether it did locate the root directory or not.