# JSP in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

I have a JSP page like index of my application, it is located in */resources/jsp/index.jsp*. I've set for when a certain route to parth this page is called. But I get a `404` when I open localhost because SpringBoot is putting **.vm** extension at the end of the file. 
How do I fix this?

Log

```
2015-07-15 08:39:51.226 ERROR 3977 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] org.apache.velocity                      : ResourceManager : unable to find resource '/jsp/index.jsp.vm' in any resource loader.
2015-07-15 08:39:51.290 ERROR 3977 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] org.apache.velocity                      : ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'error.vm' in any resource loader.
```

Index API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getIndex() {
        return new ModelAndView("/jsp/index.jsp");
    }
```

This happens even I put JSP extension in configuration
Application.properties

```
spring.application.name=VeiculoService

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/oknok

spring.data.rest.baseUri=/api

spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.http.gzip.enabled=true

spring.view.suffix= .jsp

management.context-path=/actuator

info.app.name=OKNOK Admin
info.app.description=OKNOK
info.app.version=${project.version}

server.port=${port:8181}
server.servletPath=/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot has [some limitations in handling JSPs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations). Precisely, it suggests to keep the JSPs inside the `src/main/webapp` folder, and change the packaging from `jar` to `war`.

Comment: You saved me. Why couldn't I notice this link? I wasted all day

Comment: I elaborated a bit more about this folder location in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43923483/772981). Other acceptable paths are `public` and `static`, but never ever `resources` :)