# Serving static contents in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a new poc for web application from Spring Boot. The packaging type of my application in war. In this all i want is to display some contents on a jsp. For that i have created a small jsp, and requierd css/images/js files i have put in resources/static folder. So my static folder contains css/images/js folders. I've added following code in my configuration file. My configuration extends from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    String[] pathPatterns = {"/components/**", "/images/**", "/scripts/**", "/styles/**"};
    String[] resourceLocations = {"classpath:/static/components/", "classpath:/static/images/", "classpath:/static/scripts/, classpath:/static/styles/"};
    registry.addResourceHandler(pathPatterns).addResourceLocations(resourceLocations);
}
```

However, my jsp does not get the reference of these file.

JSP Code

How to solve above problem..

Second concern, as per the spring boot reference documentation, it serves the static content which are located in static folder. that means i should be able to access files from my static folder directly in below way

http://localhost:8080/styles/main.css

But this is also not working

Third Issue - static contents are served by default servlet ..is this true that Default servlet in enabled by default in Spring Boot application

Please Help

Comment: To me it is not quite clear what your main issue is. I do see a problem with your above code example cause that would mean that for instance a file that lives in `/static/styles/` , i.e. `main.css` will be served using `/components/main.css`, `/images/main.css`, `/scripts/main.css` and `/styles/main.css`. Besides that what is your issue with the default servlet? Which is btw not true. All of the requests are routed through your `DispatcherServlet` so you can apply Security on top if you want to.

Comment: Below are my configuration which are not working

Comment: Below are my configuration which are not working ....main.css present in src/main/resources/static folder. ...i have added the resource handler as follows  String[] pathPatterns = {"/styles/**"};
String[] resourceLocations = {"classpath:/resources/static/styles/"};
registry.addResourceHandler(pathPatterns).addResourceLocations(resourceLocations);   .....Then i access using http://localhost:8080/demo/styles/main.css ..but fails...then i tries w/o context root..http://localhost:8080/styles/main.css..still failed....can you please guide

Comment: If your files are living in `src/main/resources/static/styles` there is no need to add this to your `ResourceHandler` manually since everything in static will be linked by default. I do assume you have another issue. Did you checked the mappings while starting your application in debug mode?

Comment: It worked..So i was bypassing dispatcher servlet in my url..when i added that it started working..thanks...Can you please tell me how the Default Servlet works? In the end..are all static contents handled by Default Servlet??? i.e if if the request first goes to Dispatcher Servlet.it will pass the request to Default Servlet??

Comment: I didn't dig deeper in the Frameworks sourcecode but I'm pretty sure there is no `DefaultServlet` involved at all. The mapping is registered in the `DispatcherServlet` which is afaik routing the request to a `ResourceServlet` which is then delivering the content.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the static resources inside `src/main/resources/static` folder works for me without any *addResourceHandlers* configuration. For example, I have a css file at

```
src/main/resources/static/public/css/styles.css
```

which I refer from my JSP like this:

```
<link href="/public/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You should have put your JSPs inside `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`, and set the packaging to `war` rather than `jar`, due to [the limitations of having JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429427/jsp-in-spring-boot/31432549#31432549) in Spring Boot.

Comment: Agree with the limitation for jsp..but as per documentation styles/images/js files being the static content , i have put them under resources/static folder...but this is not working...i belive with my current configuration..if i hit url http://localhost:8080/demo/styles/main.css..it should get displayed in browser...

Comment: I agree, updated my answer. (The "demo" above is a typo, no?)

Comment: demo is not a typo..it a context root to  my application. Thanks for reply Sanjay.. how to do you access the css directly in browser?? can yo ushare the sample url

Comment: Below are my configuration which are not working ....main.css present in src/main/resources/static folder. ...i have added the resource handler as follows  String[] pathPatterns = {"/styles/**"};
String[] resourceLocations = {"classpath:/resources/static/styles/"};
registry.addResourceHandler(pathPatterns).addResourceLocations(resourceLocations);   .....Then i access using http://localhost:8080/demo/styles/main.css ..but fails...then i tries w/o context root..http://localhost:8080/styles/main.css..still failed....can you please guide